# Making each module expose an interface

Tags: c

Is this a good/correct way to write a robust C program?

```
//File1 => Module1.c

static int Fun(int);

struct{
int (*pFn)(int)
}Interface;

static int Fun(int){
//do something
}

Interface* Init(void)
{
  Interface *pInterface = malloc(sizeof(Interface));
  pInterface->pFn = Fun;
  return pInterface;
}

//File 2 
main()
{
  Interface *pInterface1 = Init();
  pInterface1->pFn(5);
}
```

My intention is to make each module expose an interface.  Give your thoughts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily a design review.

Answer (score 2):

1. You probably intended to write

   ```
   typedef struct {
       int (*pFn)(int)
   } Interface;
   ```
2. Use member names which are more descriptive than `pFn`. I hope that this was just as an example to post here.
3. Yes this approach can work well. I have worked on a bigger project where we used this OO-light approach for C by having an interface struct and each backend would fill it with it's own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands it won't compile.  The `Interface` structure is not in a header file and so `main` has no knowledge of it.  Also your `malloc(sizeof(Interface))` will not compile as C (C++ will be happy) as it needs `struct` before the `Interface`, which makes me think you are using C++. And with C++ you can define interfaces, classes that implement interfaces, and objects that instantiate the classes, so you seem to be reinventing things.